# How can I modify my RPN to handle saturation (in turn, turning it into an SRPN in turn)?

Tags: java, stack

I have some Java code that I have been working on. It's still in its rough stages so I haven't changed much formatting or simplified it as much as I will.

I need my code to be able to handle saturation. At the moment, when typing an equation such as:

```
2147483647
2
+
=
```

it will give me -2147483647 and not saturate correctly. Vice versa, if I do:

```
-2147483647
2
-
=
```

it will give me +2147483647.

So I know it isn't working correctly.

Here is the current code:

```
public class calculator {

private Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();


  public void prompt(String s) {
    if (s.equals("+")) {
      int input_1 = stack.pop();
      int input_2 = stack.pop();
      int outcome = input_2 + input_1;
      stack.push(outcome);
    }
    else if (s.equals("-")) {
      int input_1 = stack.pop();
      int input_2 = stack.pop();
      int outcome = input_2 - input_1;
      stack.push(outcome);
      
    }
   
    else if (s.equals("=")) {
      System.out.println(stack.peek());
    }
    else {
      try {
        int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
        stack.push(i);

      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Unrecognized operator or operand "+ s);
      }
    }
```

Any help at all is much appreciated. I am trying to keep the overall structure of the coding the same.

Comment: What do you mean by "saturation"?  What *should* this be doing in these cases?

Comment: Are you referring to the *integer overflow* as saturation? Use a `Long` instead if your values won't fit in an `Integer`.

Comment: SRPN is a reverse Polish notation calculator with the extra feature that all arithmetic is saturated, i.e. when it reaches the maximum value that can be stored in a variable, it stays at the maximum rather than wrapping around.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to have saturated math is to perform operation on longs, they 64 bit, so there is no overflow for 32 bit integers, for example:

```
public static int saturatedAdd(int a, int b) {
    long r = (long) a + b;
    return (int) Math.max(Integer.MIN_VALUE, Math.min(Integer.MAX_VALUE, r));
}
```

by casting `a` to long we're getting correct result without over/under flow

next step is to bound long value by using min/max